# discord.py Chunk kick command

Tags: discord, discord.py

```py
  @commands.command()
  async def chunkkick(self, ctx, members: commands.Greedy[discord.Member]):
      embed = discord.Embed(description="<:ocheckmark:839069223749812264>  "+f"Successfully chunk kicked ".join([member for member in members]), color=discord.Color.orange())
      for member in members:
          await member.kick(reason=f"{ctx.author} | User was in a chunk kick")
      await ctx.reply(embed=embed, mention_author=False)
```

I am making a chunk kick command that kicks multiple users at once. It stopped working when I added `.join`. I am also not receiving errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try using single quotes instead of double quotes and you need two of them. Like so:

```
  @commands.command()
  async def chunkkick(self, ctx, members: commands.Greedy[discord.Member]):
      embed = discord.Embed(description="<:ocheckmark:839069223749812264>  "+f"Successfully chunk kicked {''.join([member for member in members])}, color=discord.Color.orange())
      for member in members:
          await member.kick(reason=f"{ctx.author} | User was in a chunk kick")
      await ctx.reply(embed=embed, mention_author=False)
```

Since python thinks you ended the string with the double quote
Its like doing

```
"Hello"World"
```

Comment: i know im a bit late and I was asking about the same thing, and just a side note you don't need to switch you can do \" which makes it register as a character inside a string instead of what defines a string.